# Complex number and product of roots

Tags: complex-numbers

For a second order ODE

y''+10y'+ 21y=0

which was reduced to this quadratic  expression
x^2+10x+21=0

- is there any way to tell whether the expression is bounded that is y(x) is either periodic or has a limit 0 as x tends to infinity?

*Does periodic means having only complex solutions?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discriminant

Comment: In the example with coefficients $(a,b,c)=(1,10,21)$ you get only real solutions $-5+2$ and $-5-2$, so that the solution on $x\in[0,\infty)$ is bounded.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the second part, in the differential equation
$$
ay''(x)+by'(x)+cy(x)=0
$$
you would need $b=0$ and $ac>0$ to get periodic solutions. With complex, but not purely imaginary eigenvalues you get oscillating solutions where the amplitude changes with an exponential function.

Comment: Oh then how do i find whether the solution to the DE is bounded or not? Such as y"+10y'+89y=0

Comment: An exponential function is never bounded. You need to tell the restrictions on the domain.

Comment: Bounded here means that the limit of the solution tends to 0 as x tends to infinity or that the solution is periodic.

Comment: The real part of a complex root is $-\frac{b}2$, so if $b\ge 0$ and the discriminant condition is satisfied, you get bounded solutions.

Comment: Ok thanks but why is this so?

Comment: See the answer of Yiyuan Lee for the solution formula. And I have to correct myself, in the case where $a$ is different from $1$, it is the sign of $-\frac{b}{2a}$ that determines boundedness.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to calculate the discriminant, that is $\Delta=b^2-4ac$, if $\Delta >0$ the equation has two dinstinct real solutions, if $\Delta=0$ then it has a repeated real solution and if $\Delta<0$ then it has no real solutions.
Note that a quadratic with real coefficents cannot have a complex and a real solution.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that you want to solve the quadratic equation, $ax^2 + bx + c = 0$. The quadratic formula gives the two roots as

$$x = \frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a}$$

Now, take a look at the surd, $\sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}$. If $b^2 - 4ac$ was negative, then the roots would be complex, because the square root of a negative real number is imaginary.

Intuitively, if $b^2 - 4ac$ is positive, then there will be two distinct real roots. If $b^2 - 4ac$ is zero, then both roots will be the same.

This $b^2 - 4ac$ is what we call the discriminant of the quadratic equation.